# How to get the large picture from feed with graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When loading the Facebook feeds from one page, if a picture exist in the feed, I want to display the large picture.

How can I get with the `graph API` ? The picture link in the feed is not the large one.

Thanks.

Comment: The current answer is not valid any more. Please update your chosen answer. @Benjamin Kuijten has the right answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a new method to get a big image. it was born after the previews method doesn't works

```
     /**
     * return a big url of facebook
     * works onky for type PHOTO
     * @param picture 
     * @param is a post type link
     * @return url of image
     */
    @Transactional
    public String getBigImageByFacebookPicture(String pictrue,Boolean link){
        if(link && pictrue.contains("url=http")){
            String url = pictrue.substring(pictrue.indexOf("url=") + 4);
            try {
                url = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Big image for Facebook link not found: ");
                sb.append(link);
                loggerTakePost.error(sb.toString());
                return null;
            }
            return url;
        }else{
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(pictrue).get();
                return doc.select("#fbPhotoImage").get(0).attr("src");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Big image for Facebook link not found: ");
                sb.append(link);
                loggerTakePost.error(sb.toString());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Enjoy your large image :)

Comment: your answer solved the problem for me, I recommend it to everybody

Comment: I asked the question, and for now, it seems your answer is the best solution. great job.

Comment: for all that used this answer and want to remove the 130x130 no matter if it's 130x130 or s433x23 or p43x43
check this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313382/remove-dynamic-substring-from-string/26313575#26313575

Comment: Changing CDN urls are a bad idea

Comment: Yes, i know, it has changed!

Comment: Since it has changed and parsing the photo url doesnt work anymore then it should not be marked as correct answer. The Answer by JK Laiho is correct in my opinion. It not only does its work but also uses the Facebook api as well instead of fething things from a html document.

Comment: @SilvioTroia how can i get post's pictures

Comment: @SilvioTroia how can i get post's pictures, i have json data like on 0th position i getting `id:454544544_45454454` `created_time:"2015-10-12` and the `story` so how can i get the picture of the story, or any user shared with me the pictures or changed profile pictures etc.

Answer (score 45):

The [Graph API photo object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) has a `picture` connection (similar to that the user object has):

> *“The album-sized view of the photo. […] Returns: HTTP 302 redirect to the URL of the picture.”*

So requesting `https://graph.facebook.com/{object-id-from-feed}/picture` will redirect you to the album-sized version of the photo immediately. (Usefull not only for displaying it in a browser, but also if f.e. you want to download the image to your server, using cURL with follow_redirect option set.)

---

**Edit:**

Beginning with API v2.3, the `/picture` edge for feed posts is deprecated.
However, as a *field* the picture can still be requested – but it will be a small one.

But `full_picture` is available as well.

So `/{object-id-from-feed}?fields=picture,full_picture` can be used to request those, or they can be requested directly with the rest of feed data, like this `/page-id/feed?fields=picture,full_picture,…` (additional fields, such as message etc., must be specified the same way.)

Comment: Worked form me. No need to api facebook for each post :)

Comment: This is the real deal. Don't mess with absolute file url's

Comment: I was hoping there was such a setting. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You're great! I've wasted hours of searching but nobody else mentioned the mystical `full_picture` param

Comment: `full_picture` has two problems: (1) It only fetches a single image, when some posts have multiple images attached, and (2) It only returns a 720px wide image (at least on the company Facebook Page I tested it on) and not the higher resolution image. Instead you need to find the actual ID of the image/attachment itself and then ask the API for `/IMAGE_ID_HERE?fields=images`.

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me :
getting the picture link from the feed and replacing "`_s.jpg`" with "`_n.jpg`"

Comment: I had to resort to that, too, but it felt really dirty and fragile. Still looking for a better way.

Comment: Nice, its working. I feel like n stands for normal, while I put b i got the bigger one.

Comment: I had to resort to this as well. It's a shame that Facebook doesn't provide for this obviously necessary functionality in it's API.

Comment: @jokeefe
try CBroe answer.

Comment: @user1105951 I tried CBroe's answer. That does not work anymore. It returns an `OAuthException` with the message `"(#100) No node specified"`.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Is there still not a better way of doing this?

Comment: _o gives the original image, if you want a drop in solution, see my answer below.

Comment: update: please first try @Silvio Troia answer.
It seems currently the best way.

Comment: Ten years later, and I don't think this works anymore.

Answer (score 16):

OK, I found a better way. When you retrieve a feed with the graph API, any feed item with a type of `photo` will have a field called `object_id`, which is not there for plain `status` type items. Query the Graph API with that ID, e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890`. Note that the object ID isn't an underscore-separated value like the main ID of that feed item is.

The result of the `object_id` query will be a new JSON dictionary, where you will have a `source` attribute containing a URL for an image that has so far been big enough for my needs.

There is additionally an `images` array that contains more image URLs for different sizes of the image, but the sizes there don't seem to be predictable, and don't all actually correspond to the physical dimensions of the image behind that URL.

I still wish there was a way to do this with a single Graph API call, but it doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: If the “album size version” is OK for you, then there is a simpler way – see my answer.

Comment: you're right. This is the most standard way to do so. (less chance to break)

Comment: Most safe way, but...performance loss. Especially when you like to display the feed / posts in a custom way on a website and have to do an extra Graph Api call for "every" post to get a link to the larger picture.

Answer (score 8):

For high res image links from:

- Link posts
- Video posts
- Photo posts

I use the following:

**Note:** The reason I give the `_s -> _o` hack precedence over the `object_id/picture` approach is because the object_id approach was not returning results for all images.

```
var picture = result.picture;
if (picture) {
    if (result.type === 'photo') {
        if (picture.indexOf('_s') !== -1) {
            console.log('CONVERTING');
            picture = picture.replace(/_s/, '_o');
        } else if (result.object_id) {
            picture = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + result.object_id + '/picture?width=9999&height=9999';
        }
    } else {
        var qps = result.picture.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < qps.length; i++) {
            var qp = qps[i];
            var matches = qp.match(/(url=|src=)/gi);
            if (matches && matches.length > 0) picture = decodeURIComponent(qp.split(matches[0])[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works extremely well. You can build in a check for if a picture doesn't load from changing _s to _o or _n (easy using Picasso), to just get the object id and get the source from there via another api call.

Comment: Good suggestion! I didn't really need that functionality but that would be a good idea for someone who really needed the largest image.

Comment: Since this still seems to be the best method I've seen, here's an update. Everything finishes with `_n.jpg` or `_n.png` now. No need to replace those. Instead you have to get rid of the `/p130x130` or `/s130x130`.

Comment: I think this method is outdated and no longer works. Facebook have secured their image URLs with a hash that cannot be manipulated.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you need two different solutions to fully fix this.

1] https://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}/picture

This solution works fine for images and videos posted to Facebook, but sadly, it returns small images in case the original image file was not uploaded to Facebook directly. (When posting a link to another site on your page for example).

2] The Facebook Graph API provides a way to get the full images in the feed itself for those external links. If you add 'full_picture' to the fields like in this example below when calling the API, you will be provided a link to the higher resolution version.

https://graph.facebook.com/your_facebook_id/posts?fields=id,link,full_picture,description,name&access_token=123456

Combining these two solutions I ended up filtering the input in PHP as follows:

```
if ( isset( $post['object_id'] ) ){
    $image_url  =   'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post['object_id'].'/picture';

}else if ( isset( $post['full_picture'] ) ) {
    $image_url  =   $post['full_picture'];

}else{
    $image_url  =   '';
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but...the full_picture link unfortunately points to a rather small image :(

Comment: Your right @YoupTube After some more experimentation I will need to update my answer...

Comment: From another post I learned to use "attachments". That one is working for me. It includes a Media node with Image and source. Try it yourself!

Comment: This is the best solution for the latest API here, but @YoupTube solution is better, you just need to do a little research for "attachments" attribute :)
  
BenjaminKuijten I advice you to edit your post with attachments it will be great.

Comment: If you plan to edit take in mind that you should keep your logic and add the attachments case on top, because some times there are not attachments and the the only way left is the "/picture" solution.

Comment: This helped me out as well and was the only solution working so far, for the latest API.

Answer (score 1):

See: http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/facebook/api/facebook-graph-api/docs/reference/pictures

Just put "?type=large" after the URL to get the big picture.

Comment: I feel like this is probably the most viable solution here. Worth noting that /me/picture?type=large will 302 redirect to the image itself. If you want the actual data, including the image URL then you will need to pass the ?redirect=false parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mattdlockyer for the JS solution. Here is a similar thing in PHP:

```
$posts = $facebook->api('/[page]/posts/', 'get');

foreach($posts['data'] as $post)
{
    if(stristr(@$post['picture'], '_s.'))
    {
        $post['picture'] = str_replace('_s.', '_n.', @$post['picture']);
    }

    if(stristr(@$post['picture'], 'url='))
    {
        parse_str($post['picture'], $picturearr);
        if($picturearr['url'])
            $post['picture'] = $picturearr['url'];
    }

    //do more stuff with $post and $post['picture'] ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After positive comment from @Lachezar Todorov I decided to post my current approach (**including paging** and using **Json.NET** ;):

```
try
{
    FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionFacebookAccessToken].ToString());

    JObject posts = JObject.Parse(fbClient.Get(String.Format("/{0}/posts?fields=message,picture,link,attachments", FacebookPageId)).ToString());
    JArray newsItems = (JArray)posts["data"];

    List<NewsItem> result = new List<NewsItem>();

    while (newsItems.Count > 0)
    {
        result.AddRange(GetItemsFromJsonData(newsItems));

        if (result.Count > MaxNewsItems)
        {
            result.RemoveRange(MaxNewsItems, result.Count - MaxNewsItems);
            break;
        }

        JToken paging = posts["paging"];

        if (paging != null)
        {
            if (paging["next"] != null)
            {
                posts = JObject.Parse(fbClient.Get(paging.Value<String>("next")).ToString());
                newsItems = (JArray)posts["data"];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And the helper method to retieve individual items:

```
private static IEnumerable<NewsItem> GetItemsFromJsonData(IEnumerable<JToken> items)
{
    List<NewsItem> newsItems = new List<NewsItem>();

    foreach (JToken item in items.Where(item => item["message"] != null))
    {
        NewsItem ni = new NewsItem
        {
            Message = item.Value<String>("message"),
            DateTimeCreation = item.Value<DateTime?>("created_time"),
            Link = item.Value<String>("link"),
            Thumbnail = item.Value<String>("picture"),

            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319242/simplify-looking-up-nested-json-values-with-json-net/28359155#28359155
            Image = (String)item.SelectToken("attachments.data[0].media.image.src") ?? (String)item.SelectToken("attachments.data[0].subattachments.data[0].media.image.src")
        };
        newsItems.Add(ni);
    }

    return newsItems;

}
```

NewsItem class I use:

```
public class NewsItem
{
  public String Message { get; set; }
  public DateTime? DateTimeCreation { get; set; }
  public String Link { get; set; }
  public String Thumbnail { get; set; }
  public String Image { get; set; }
}
```