# Remove dynamic substring from string

Tags: objective-c

If I have random strings, I need to remove a substring like this :

"fsdfsd/p90x95/fsdfsdf"    >>>  "fsdfsd/fsdfsdf"

"fsdfsd/s110x72/fsdfsdsdff" >>> "fsdfsd/fsdfsdsdff"

"/sdfsdfd/fsdfsd/t800x1024/fsdfsdsdff" >>> "/sdfsdfd/fsdfsd/fsdfsdsdff"

And I need to remove the substring everytime, when ONLY fixed (rule) is:
'/' optionally letter(s) number(s) 'x' number(s) '/'

How can I detect this substring and remove it for all cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression, `/\w+x\d+`

```
NSString *str = @"/sdfsdfd/fsdfsd/t800x1024/fsdfsdsdff";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/\\w+x\\d+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString); // output: /sdfsdfd/fsdfsd/fsdfsdsdff
```